# Can I use Arcane Cascade if I Cast a Spell at the end of my previous turn?

Tags: pathfinder-2e

[Arcane Cascade](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=756) reads, in part:

> **Requirements** You used your most recent action to Cast a Spell or make a Spellstrike.

On turn 1, I move and then I cast a two-action spell.

On turn 2, I would like to begin that turn by using Arcane Cascade.

Does that spell I cast previous turn count as my "most recent action" for the purposes of Arcane Cascade's requirements, or does the most recent action mean 'within the same turn'?

Answer (score 6):

Though there is no specific verbiage one way or another in the rule books, [this interview](https://youtu.be/Jy_sIdmsyKM?t=113) with Lead Designer Logan Bonner clarifies that effect that care about "your next action" and "your last action" do not carry over across turns.

Comment: Huh. I’ve literally never played at a table that didn’t allow those conditions to carry across. Good to know.

Answer (score 6):

## No

The answer from [3Doubloons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/8493/3doubloons) isn't wrong, but it's outdated. The rules-as-intended clarification from Logan Bonner is now the official, rules-as-written answer.

While the original Secrets of Magic book was ambiguous and [Archives of Nethys](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=756) as of today still follows the original wording, Arcane Cascade has actually been [errata'd](https://paizo.com/pathfinder/faq) with the Remaster.

Original:

> **Requirements**
> You used your most recent action to Cast a Spell or make a Spellstrike.

[Errata](https://paizo.com/pathfinder/faq) (See: "**Secrets of Magic Errata (Remaster Compatibility)**, Page 38"):

> **Requirements**
> You used your most recent action **this turn** to Cast a Spell or make a
> Spellstrike. You need to meet this requirement only to enter the
> stance, not to remain in it.

The primary change resolves a rule ambiguity where you *technically* couldn't stay in Arcane Cascade (you can only remain in a Stance as long as you meet the requirement, which is that your last action was to cast a spell or spellstrike, but Arcane Cascade is an action, so you no longer meet the requirements as soon as you enter it), but Paizo has also clarified exactly this question.

Note that the Magus will not appear in any remastered books, so this change is not written down in any rulebooks - so this is an errata. You can expect this change to be accurately reflected on Archives of Nethys when the changes from the remaster are live.